# C++ Push back a vector into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, push, back

This is the vector I created;

`std::vector<std::vector<Vertex*>*> Vertices;`

And I'm having trouble figuring out how to push back the `std::vector<Vertex*>` into the outer
vector.

So what im kind of trying to do is:

`Vertices.push_back(new vector().push_back(new Vertex()));`

but I'm not sure what the right way to do it is. Hope you people get the idea.

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving.

Comment: You need to push a `std::vector<Vertex*>*`. Figure out how to get a pointer to an `std::vector<Vertex*>` first, then push it into the outed vector.

Comment: Don't try and do that in a single line of code. Do it step by step. And make sure you really really want all those pointers.

Comment: I second `Mat` here, *why* do you want a `vector` of *pointers* and not a `vector` of *values* ? You should use `std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>>` here, *most probably*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it is sometimes OK to make a vector of pointers (preferably, smart pointers), it is never a good idea to make a vector of pointers to vectors: this complicates your memory management for no good reason.

The best solution is to use a vector of vertex objects, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vertex> > vertices;
```

This would let you push back like this:

```
vector<Vertex> vv;
vv.push_back(Vertex(...));
vertices.push_back(vv);
```

If you want a vector of descendants of `Vertex` with polymorphic behavior, use a vector of vectors of pointers:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vertex*> > vertices;
...
vector<Vertex*> vv;
vv.push_back(new Vertex(...));
vertices.push_back(vv);
```

Note that if you do this, you are on the hook for freeing the `Vertex` objects inside the vector. A better solution would be using smart pointers - say, `unique_ptr`, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unique_ptr<Vertex> > > vertices;
```

`unique_ptr` would take care of freeing `Vertex` objects automatically.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the memory. I know for a normal vector, the main vector is stored in stack but it's elements are stored in heap. So, if a vector is pushed onto a vector of vectors, will it be copied to heap?

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu The part of the vector stored on the stack is a pair of pointers. That's the "main vector". If you push it onto a vector of vectors, the pair of pointers would be copied into that vector's content, which is on the heap.

Comment: cool thanks. So, only the vector is copied to but not the elements.which were already in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a single line. But you can do it in 4;

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vertex*>*> Vertices;
std::vector<Vertex*> * vec = new std::vector<Vertex*>;
vec.push_back(new Vertex()); // fill the inner vector as many times as you need
Vertices.push_back(vec);
```

But why you would want to do that? You will leak memory if you won't call `delete` for each element of the outer vector, but before doing that you will need to call `delete` on every `Vertex*` in inside vectors.

Edit: for a better way of storing Vertex without leaking memory look at dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: I'm only learning c++ so I don't always come up with the simplest solutions for problems.

Comment: @user3597902 If you are learning C++ then you should remember to use `new` as little as possible in favour of containers.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable. For example, try:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vertex*>> Vertices;
Vertices.push_pack(std::vector<Vertex*>());
Vertices.back().push_back(new Vertex[8]);
```

Following this code, you do not need to use any extra memory.
To access or modify the element located in the i'th member of first vector, and j'th member of the second vector, and the 6th member of the array, you can use:

```
Vertices.at(i).at(j)[6];
```